# Windows 10 loses settings of keyboard layout shortcuts (hotkeys for input languages)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have two input languages in Windows - English and Ukrainian.

I configured them to have Ctrl-Shift-1 and Ctrl-Shift-2 shortcuts respectively.

However this setting keeps disappearing all the time and shortcuts are reset to none (either one or both of them) after 5-10 minutes of use.  Any ideas, why this happens?

Upd: the issue seemed to have gone away after I disabled synchronization of Windows settings, however after installing Anniversary Update the issue happens again all the time (and synchronization is disabled this time).

Comment: I have observed this problem (in February 2017) on a standalone PC used by a single user. I suspect some Windows 10 update has caused this, since the shortcuts worked well for several months after upgrade to Win 10.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela So the below solution is not sufficient in your case or you're looking for a technical explanation why this occurs? The below seems to be a workaround the reason seems to indicate it's a Microsoft bug so I just wanted to confirm what more in particular you may be looking for here since your bounty indicates "*This question has not received enough attention.*". I'm sure there are other method than that mentioned to apply applicable settings per session, logon, etc.

Comment: @Walmart I’m looking for a clarification of the answer, which seems to have a useful solution but with insufficient details on how to do set the shortcuts in a permanent way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turns out that the shortcuts are lost when the other session
(non-interactive one) interacts. 
The solution is to copy the settings to Login screen session
and to default settings for other user. 
This prevents the settings from being lost. 
I believe, it's a bug in Windows, so that it wipes the shortcuts
if they are not set in the logon screen session.

The
"Control Panel"->"All Control Panel Items"->"Language "->"Advanced settings"
Control Panel page has an "Apply language settings to the welcome screen, system accounts and new user accounts" link in the first section
(captioned "Override for Windows display language"). 
Once you click it, a "Region" dialog is opened.
On the "Administrative" tab, the top part has "Copy settings..." button.

[image: Copying language settings to system accounts and new user accounts]

Comment: could you explain how to do this?

Comment: @DanHolli The `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Language\Advanced settings` Control Panel page has "Apply language settings to the welcome screen, system accounts and new user accounts" link in the first section (captioned Override for Windows display language). Once you click it, Region dialog is opened. On Administrative tab, the top part has "Copy settings..." button. That's it.

Comment: you should add that to your answer for anyone else that has the same question, so it's just right there, I don't need the info, but someone else might.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoS You should add another answer to this post since there was a bounty specifically asking for more detail. So rather than editing this answer, you should create a new answer and put in all the detail, screen shots, etc. and if that's what is needed, it would be worthy of the bounty and the upvotes, etc. of those which it helps.

Comment: Since about Windows 10 version 1809, it is easier to find this dialog via: `Settings\Time & Language\Language\Administrative language settings`. 
Also, if anyone wants to make this bug more visible to Microsoft - consider upvoting related FeedbackHub suggestions - I've collected several links [here](https://superuser.com/a/1368543/135260).

Answer (score 0):

(I've also included this answer in the linked question.)

This has been a recurring problem for me as well. Recently the program [Keyman](https://keyman.com/) has been released as free software, and it enables you to create keyboard shortcuts for keyboards just like Windows does. (You can create shortcuts either for Keyman keyboards, or for the Windows keyboards you already have installed.)