# Some specific languages keep disappearing from the language toolbar in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, language, toolbar

I have been using language toolbar and 4 different keyboard languages (English, Spanish, Russian and Latvian) without any issues for about half a year in Windows 10.

This morning I suddenly realized that Spanish language has disappeared from the language toolbar. But it still was showed as "installed" in the language preferences!

I experimented with different kind of options, set the "old type of language bar" and from there I could switch to Spanish.

Then I realized language switching hot  keys do not work, even if they appear to be set, just do not work.

In the meantime, now Latvian language disappeared from the language bar, and the "old type of language bar" also disappered.

I am very confused why languages keep disappearing from the language bar!

Comment: "I am very confused why languages keep disappearing from the language bar!" - My guess you still have a language pack for a previous Windows 10 feature update installed.  Uninstall all language packs except the primary one, then reinstall all the language packs, that should solve the problem.

Comment: Try https://superuser.com/questions/1096411/windows-10-loses-settings-of-keyboard-layout-shortcuts-hotkeys-for-input-langua

Comment: I have the very same problem - languages disappear from language bar. The difference is that in my case the also disappear from Old Language Bar. They reappear after I sign out and sign in again, but that is super frustrating.