# Windows individual language shortcuts do not reliably work

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, input-languages, chinese

Update:
The problem is rather different than it seemed when this problem was first posed. The particular languages which work seem to depend on the mood of my computer with no particular rhyme or reason. Currently when I press my keyboard shortcuts online Chinese switches and it will not switch back to English, however at another time it could be only English and Russian. Has anyone else encountered this problem, and if so have a solution to it?

***Old Post:***

*For switching the language in Windows, I've changed from a shortcut which scrolls through a list of languages, to having individual shortcuts for each language.*

*This is working fine except for with Chinese, where the shortcut will not switch to the language. I've tried switching between using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> as the modifier, however neither works.*

Comment: Did you mean when you use the shortcut, it will switch any other languages one by one, but not Chinese? And you can manually select Chinese? It looked like that it just ignored Chinese?

Comment: So what would happen was I could use alt + shift to go through a list of all the languages, that worked fine. When I wanted to use alt + shift + 1 for English alt + shift + 2 for Chinese .... etc, it would work for all languages except for Chinese where it would just stay on the language I had selected. I tried it again the other day and had a different problem where other languages wouldn't work. I will test it again when I get home and post an update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 loses settings of keyboard layout shortcuts (hotkeys for input languages)](https://superuser.com/questions/1096411/windows-10-loses-settings-of-keyboard-layout-shortcuts-hotkeys-for-input-langua)