# How to Stop Windows from Resetting Language Shortcut Config?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, language

A consistent issue between all computers I have owned:

I speak a few languages and learning even more, so instead of using Windows + Space it's more convenient for me to go to Language->Spelling, Typing, and Keyboard Settings-> Advanced Keyboard Settings-> Language Bar Options, and set different shortcuts for each language.

The problem is, pretty much anytime I restart the device, or my computer goes to sleep, it gets rid of all the shortcuts except for Japanese and Chinese.

Some things to consider:

- These computers have had separate accounts, and my brother who has
  similar needs experiences the same issue.
- I have also seen some cases around that have the same thing happen to
  them: all language keyboards are cleared out except for Japanese and
  Chinese. It might be because of their IMEs, but I also have Korean,
  which is still reset.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://superuser.com/a/1111605/135260)?

Comment: I did this and will post in a day or so if it doesn't work. Sometimes, it will randomly stay in the config which I had it, so I'm gonna give it a few chances to appear just in case.

Comment: BTW, make sure you reboot just after adjusting that setting.